# How to calculate the number of months between two DateTimes?

Tags: c#, datetime

Requirements:

- Calculate the number of months
  between two dates: receiveDate and
  dueDate.
- Both optimistic and pessimistic
  calculations are needed

Assumptions:

- dueDate will always be the last day of the month.

I've already figured out the pessimistic calculation (meaning a single day overdue counts as a whole month:

```
if(receiveDate > dueDate)
    receiveDate.Month - dueDate.Month + (receiveDate.Year - dueDate.Year) * 12;
```

Doing a search on the internet turned up several similar examples to confirm this.

Now my instincts tell me the optimistic calculation will just be the same minus one month but for some reason it just doesn't feel right. Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't understand the 'optimistic/pessimistic' thing. Is the number of months between two dates defined as 'the number of months which have one or more days between the two dates, inclusive'? In which case wouldn't there be just one correct answer.

Comment: It really comes down to how you view partial months. In one case partial months are ignored in the other they are counted like a whole month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; if you're looking for the number of *complete* months between the two dates,  subtracting 1 (assuming the `receiveDate` doesn't fall on the last day of the month, in which case you will have a remainder of 0 days either way) will get you your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep days of month in your calculus I think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula calculates the number of months between the first of the receivedDate's month to the first of the dueDate's month. As most time elements in TimeSpan are expressed as TotalXXX, it seems weird that they left out a TotalMonths and a TotalYears.

I think it's because there aren't a fixed number of days from month to month, so it's hard to know what makes most sense in terms of how to express the fractional remainder.

My formula is this...

```
int nMonthDiff_FirstToFirst = DateTime.Now.Month - testDate.Month + ((DateTime.Now.Year - testDate.Year)* 12);

double dMonthDiff = (double)nMonthDiff_FirstToFirst + (DateTime.Now - testDate.AddMonths(nMonthDiff_FirstToFirst)).TotalDays / (double)DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
```

So what I'm doing is basically getting the month difference like you are (first of the month to first of the month) then I project my testDate into the future by the month difference. Then with that TimeSpan I get the TotalDays and divide that by the number of days in that month. Thus I'm representing the fractional portion in terms of remaining days of the month.

So if you were going May 5st 2012 -> June 3rd 2012, your formula would return 1 for month difference when a full month hasn't passed yet. In my formula the TotalDays of the projected date would yield a negative fractional number of days, and when added to the 'first to first' month difference, it would take it in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this extra check to get precise amount of months:

numberOfMonths = receiveDate.Month - dueDate.Month + (receiveDate.Year - dueDate.Year) * 12;
if (receiveDate.Day > dueDate.Day) numberOfMonths--;

Answer (score 0):

```
int GetMonthsCount(DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtEnd)
{
    return (int)Math.Round((dtEnd - dtStart).TotalMonths);
}
```